# How to I make a serializer from a model which has defined object (from another model)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im new to Django REST framework, but getting the hang of it. Im trying to make a serializer from the **Profile** Model but i dont know how to pass (def followers and following) into the serializer

This is the Profile Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=245, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='interests_user')
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    one_click_purchasing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    @property
    def followers(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(follow_user=self.user).count()

    @property
    def following(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follow_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follow_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    old_instance = models.ForeignKey('Follow', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is not None:
            self.old_instance = Follow.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"For: {self.user} // id: {self.id}"
```

This is the serializer I built so far,
But it doesnot work correctly, Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'count (line 40)

```
class PublicProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    follow_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

     def get_follow_user(self, obj):
        return obj.follow_user

    def get_followers(self, obj):
        # return obj.user.followers.count()
        return FollowSerializer(obj.follow_user.count())

    def get_following(self, obj):
        # return obj.user.following.count()
        return FollowSerializer(obj.user.count())  - Line 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your serializer

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers= serializers.CharField(source='followers') # the followers at source='follower should be the name of function'
    following = serializers.CharField(source='following')

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'
```

the lhs is the name you want to give to variable and the rhs is how you gonna get that value(in this case it's the functions)

Comment: When i do this. Wouldnt I do a def get_following(self,obj): afterwards?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean can you be more clear.

Comment: Finally got what you mean. Works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from rest_framework import serializer

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # hack..hack..


class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # hack..hack..


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers = FollowSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    following = FollowSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # hack..hack..

    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = (..., "followers", "following", )
```

Then you can use it with views, viewsets. If you want to use it manually, use it like this

```
# Single Instance
serializer = ProfileSerializer(single_instance)
serializer.data # This returns json
# Multiple Instances
serializer = ProfileSerializer(iterable_of_instances, many=True)
serializer.data # This returns json
```